# Updating Minecraft goes wrong

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have Minecraft on both tablet and phone, under the same account.

On my phone, it will not update to version 12.1, because it has already been installed on my tablet.

I deleted the app from my tablet, but it still will not let me update, on my phone.

How do I update my phone version of Minecraft?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to remain unspecific on your exact platform, although from what it sounds. I suspect that your phone may be unsupported by that version of minecraft. As minecraft has begun to dump their compatibility for earlier devices.